# Search a .txt file on my computer and read it for print the result in a talble

Tags: java, netbeans, import, jtable

I'm doing a project. I want to give two options for all users. The first one is the button create for create the item and the other is the "import button". With this button I want that when the user press on it they can serch in his computer files .txt and import to the project and then read the content and insert on a table.

So, I've two questions; The first one is how to import a computer file to the project? and the second one is how I read the information and put in one table?

Thank you so much,

Comment: Read more about Java I/O to learn how to create/search/read files on the File System and Java Swing (jTable) to learn how to manipulate the GUI. Sorry but we can't just give you the code, there's no fun in that, right? Here's a good place to start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BufferedReader` to read the file.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
// Or you can use
// File myFile = getFile();
// BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

String line;

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // Add the line to the table.
}
```

I can't help you with the second part very much because it's really vague, but I'll make some assumptions and give you some pointers.

Assuming your file has elements seperated by commas, you can parse it pretty easily:

```
String[] columns = line.split(",");
```

And then you can add the columns to your table.

Answer (score 0):

So you should do some research on libraries that do what you are looking to accomplish.

Here is a link about using FileChoosers. -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html 
That would be how the user 'selects' the file. There are many plugins for building forms via drag and drop, or you can go build and position them manually. In either case you need to understand forms (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/).

The last part of your question is just parsing whatever date you have and literally printing it out in some format. THere are numerous possible methods to accomplish that, but you should focus on properly building GUI forms and opening files first. Hope this helps!